# Kickstands "designed for steel frame"

Tags: steel, aluminum, kickstand

While looking for a rear kickstand, I came across one which says "designed for steel frames".

Besides carbon frame which I am pretty sure cannot be "squeezed", is there a real difference among steel frames and aluminium frames that can account for different stands, or is it more a commercial thing?

Comment: "read bike stand"?

Comment: Why would they lie?

Comment: You have to be careful with kickstands: http://surlybikes.com/info_hole/spew/kickstands_on_long_haul_truckers

Comment: @Batman, I meant rear...

Comment: @Batman what's the LHT made of? I thought it was steel.

Comment: @ChrisH - yes. But material isn't the be all end all. The tube thicknesses and stuff matter too

Comment: The chain stays are super long on the Surly bikes so they're particularly susceptible to lateral forces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to design a rear kickstand for a standard steel bicycle since all you need is a strong clamp on one of the chainstays.

For carbon, the clamping mechanism has to be designed carefully because it can neither compress the stays too much (carbon is fragile in compression) nor can it scratch the carbon too deeply (if the fibers fray, the whole structure weakens).

Aluminium is in between. The main concern with alu is that the stand can crimp or bend the chain stays if the bolts are clamped on too tight, or if there's too much of a load on the bike (full panniers) and all that stress and force is concentrated in one area.

If your bike is both expensive and made of either alu/carbon fiber, I'd either forgo using a rear kickstand, use track stands, or use center-stands that use the bridge between the rear chainstays and bottom bracket for support.

Comment: Is there a downside to a centre-mounted kickstand (assuming it fits)? They're all I've ever used, in single and double versions.

Comment: They tend to be heavier (especially double-kick stands), I think that's about it.  But most importantly - not all bikes can take center-stands because they lack the bridge or the cranks will hit.

Comment: My double is certainly heavy, but as it's there because of a toddler seat it's not such a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted the dealer, asking the same question: what is so special about steel frames, and can it be used on aluminium frame?

The answer I got was: since steel frames are normally heavier than aluminium, the label means that the kickstand has been designed for those heavy loads. Therefore it can be used also on aluminium frames.

Comment: Steel frames are only a few kilos (if that much) heavier than alu ones. My guess is that you didn't really reach the manufacturer but the reseller, who came up with a plausible sounding answer to make you happy.

Comment: @RoboKaren that is also possible

Comment: @RoboKaren is right -- I've been looking at tourer weights recently

Comment: Are you sure the dealer wasn't saying that steel frames are *more heavily built*?

Comment: The person I spoke to talked about "weight"

Comment: @L.Dutch - But a "heavyweight" frame is one that's "heavily built".

Comment: @DanielRHicks, I suspect he was having in mind "gates with 2 wheels", a.k.a. low end steel bikes.

Comment: Most kickstands would crumple under the weight of a fully loaded tourer with panniers. Center stands rock there - or  stands that support from the top tube.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just found out the reason, when I went to go purchase a kickstand for my steel framed Breezer. It has to do with the width of the chain stay.
As steel bikes are stronger then aluminium, they tend to have smaller tubes, in particular the chain-stay. As most rear mounted kickstands are designed for the thicker aluminum frames, they do not hold tight on the narrow steel framed bikes, causing them to be unstable. I found this out the hard way.

Comment: I'm not shooting the messenger but, if this is the reason, it's a poor one. Different bikes have different sized tubes and it would be much better for the manufacturer to state the range of tube diameters their stand is designed for, rather than hoping that "steel" means "narrow" and "aluminium" means "wide".

Comment: Hi, welcome CScott, it’s a fair suggestion and a well presented answer. It might not hold true in all cases, time will tell if people agree and upvote

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a real reason to make a kickstand just for steel frames, except what you mentioned about carbon.  The only thing I can think of is maybe the one "for steel frames" has a steel plate where it interfaces with the frame, and they are trying to keep galvanic corrosion away...

Comment: Galvanic corrosion wouldn't be any issue unless there was a current path through the paint.  Then you'd have to worry about simple rust with or without a kickstand

Comment: @ChrisH -- If there isn't a current path through the paint then the clamp probably isn't on tight enough.

Comment: @DanielRHicks paint is a pretty good insulator and modern paints are tough. If you clamp it so tight it damages the paint, the frame may suffer. And it will certainly allow rust to set in even if you merely crack the paint right through to bare metal.

Comment: @ChrisH - Sometime examine closely how a kickstand "bites" onto the frame.  And consider the forces on the kickstand arm.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I have fitted several, but all of the type that join both chainstays between the BB and the back wheel.  None of those has broken the paint, in fact they usually have a grippy pad of some sort. There's no way I'd fit one that's designed to chew through the paint, even though I'm probably buying a steel tourer.  So I probbly won't have the chance to examine one

Comment: @ChrisH Well, side-stands are different from those center-stands. I have had both in my hands, and the side stands you clamp onto the stands near the rear hub are definitely a danger to the paint.

Comment: @cmaster most of my experience is with the single sided type that go behind the bottom bracket (though I have a double leg centre stand on the child-carrying bike). With care they'll support a loaded tourer. The one time I hired a bike with a stand near the hub it wasn't even good at being a stand so I'll carry on avoiding them. If they're designed to bite through the paint and into the metal that's an admission from the manufacturers that the concept is on the margins of being completely unworkable, at least as a general accessory